# SwiftUI textfield height didn't change

Tags: swiftui, textfield

I have a simple TextField and set height and some other properties but the issue is textfield height didn't change, bellow is my code

```
 struct LoginView: View {

    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var password = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            TextField("Email", text: self.$email)
                .frame(height: 55)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .cornerRadius(16)
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 24)

            SecureField("Password", text: self.$password)
                .frame(height: 55)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .cornerRadius(16)
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 24)
        }
    }
}
struct LoginView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoginView()
    }
}
```

However this doesn't work.

Answer (score 31):

Lets check it!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var password = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            TextField("Email", text: self.$email)
                .frame(height: 200).border(Color.red)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .cornerRadius(16)
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 24)

            SecureField("Password", text: self.$password)
                .frame(height: 55)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .cornerRadius(16)
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 24)
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

You have to understand how View modifiers work. **Any modifier returns new View with modified Content**.

see this one :-)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var password = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            TextField("Email", text: self.$email)
                .frame(height: 200).border(Color.red)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .cornerRadius(16)
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 24)

            SecureField("Password", text: self.$email)
            .frame(height: 55)
            .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 4)
            .cornerRadius(16)
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16).stroke(Color.gray).padding(.bottom, -150).padding(.top, 50))
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 24)
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

As you can see, the styling of TextField itself is never changed, except you explicitly will change it.

Currently **TextFieldStyle public API is very limited**

```
/// A specification for the appearance and interaction of a `TextField`.
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public protocol TextFieldStyle {
}
```

You can just select one of predefined ...

```
DefaultTextFieldStyle
PlainTextFieldStyle
RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle
SquareBorderTextFieldStyle
```

**You are right! You not able to change height of TextField, its height is dependent on Font used to render it, except applying some custom TextFieldStyle** It is not documented, and could change in future version ...

**UPDATE, based on** [How to change SwiftUI TextField style after tapping on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60379010/how-to-change-swiftui-textfield-style-after-tapping-on-it) **(all credits should go to the author of this question)**

**Example of custom TextFieldStyle**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var password = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            TextField("Email", text: self.$email)
                .textFieldStyle(MyTextFieldStyle()).border(Color.blue)
        }
    }
}

struct MyTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
        configuration
        .padding(30)
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20, style: .continuous)
                .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 3)
        ).padding()
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

and final look, which is what you are looking for ...

[image]

Answer (score 26):

Use instead plain text field style like below

[image: demo]

```
TextField("Email", text: self.$email)
    .frame(height: 55)
    .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
    .padding([.horizontal], 4)
    .cornerRadius(16)
    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16).stroke(Color.gray))
    .padding([.horizontal], 24)
```

Comment: please, see my update, and an example of custom TextFieldStyle (it is not my own idea)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by doing the following:

```
TextField("Title", text: $model.text, axis: .vertical)
    .lineLimit(5...10)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to increase TextField size in SwiftUI is via `controlSize`. You can't arbitrarily control it, but it gives you some way to increase the height.

[image]

```
VStack {
    TextField(text: $email) {
        Text("Email")
    }
    .controlSize(.small)
    TextField(text: $email) {
        Text("Email")
    }
    .controlSize(.regular)
    TextField(text: $email) {
        Text("Email")
    }
    .controlSize(.large)
}
.textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
.frame(width: 270)
```