# How to change size of field in TextField?

Tags: swiftui

I need to change the size (actually just the height) of the TextField. Using `.padding()` increases just the area around the TextField, but not the field itself. I've tried some possible solutions:

1. Change the font size: This approach works, but I don't want to have a TextField with a too large text in itself.
2. Using [custom modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60375050/9557346) doesn't work. I get the message `Inheritance from non-protocol type 'TextFieldStyle'`. Seems to not working in Swift 5 anymore?

My current solution is:

```
@State private var searchText: String = ""

var body: some View {

HStack{
    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
        .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold))
    
    ZStack(alignment: .leading){
        if searchText.isEmpty { Text("search") }
        TextField("", text: $searchText,
                  onEditingChanged: { focused in
                    if focused {
                        // do something...
                    }
                  },
                  onCommit: {
                    // do something...
                  })
            .keyboardType(.alphabet)
            .disableAutocorrection(true)
            .frame(height: 50)
    }
    .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
}
.frame(height: 30)
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
.foregroundColor(.white)
.accentColor(.white)
.padding()
.background(
    Color("Color-2")
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.3), radius: 5, x: 5, y: 5)
)
.contentShape(Rectangle())
}}
```

Only the red area is "clickable"

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var stringOfText: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {

        TextField("", text: $stringOfText)
            .font(Font.system(size: 50))
            .background(Color.yellow)
            .foregroundColor(Color.clear)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .overlay(Text(stringOfText), alignment: .leading)
            .padding()
            .shadow(radius: 10)

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but what happens when you tap on the edge of the yellow rectangle? Does the cursor appear and you can type in some text? For me your solution doesn't work.

Comment: @Erik: the code is updated! try now again

Comment: Now I have a yellow rectangle, but when I tap on the rectangle nothing happens

Comment: @Erik: yes, but you can play with those numbers to reach what you want, like make a little big or small I do not know what design you want, so put time on if you like to find best size, also as you know there is other way, that is all you can do right now.

Comment: @Erik: I made another code, try the new one, if it works!

Comment: Yes, this solutions works better. It looks a little bit strange because the cursor it pretty big now, but I will check if there's a way to handle this problem. Thank you again!

Comment: @Erik: I wanted to know if it works for you, I will update my code for solving that issue as well, that is a little hard but I think I can.